# Subtract time in date value

Tags: java, date

I actually have found the last three dates and what I want to do is subtract 5 hours and 45 minutes from each date. How can  implement it?

The code I have done so far is:

```
public static List<Date> getPastThreeDays() {
    List<Date> pDates = new ArrayList<Date>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -i);
        Date date = cal.getTime();
        String pastDate = sdf.format(date);
        Date pstThreesDates;
        try {
            pstThreesDates = sdf.parse(pastDate);
            pDates.add(pstThreesDates);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return pDates;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    // for getting past three dates
    System.out.println("-----Formatted Past Three Days-----");
    List<Date> pastThreeDatesList = getPastThreeDays();
    for (Date date : pastThreeDatesList) {
        System.out.println("Orignal:" + date);
    }
```

Comment: Hint: a `Date` is just a number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch. You can get that number by calling `getTime()`. You can then subtract the number of milliseconds in 5 hours and 45 minutes. You can then call `setTime` or create a new `Date` with it...

Comment: You are already using `Calendar.add()` -- what's missing?

Comment: Also note that almost everything about dates is easier if you use classes in Java 8's `java.time` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert the date into milliseconds then substract the 5hr 45min from it as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

      System.out.println("-----Formatted Past Three Days-----");
        List<Date> pastThreeDatesList = getPastThreeDays();
        for (Date date : pastThreeDatesList) {
           System.out.println("Orignal:"+date);

          long mDateMills= date.getTime() - ((5*3600 *1000)+ 45*60*1000); //you convert your date to millisecond then subtract 5h45min( in milliseconds from it)
          String  mNewDate= millsToDateFormat(mDateMills);

          System.out.println("new Date:"+mNewDate);
        }
}

public static String millsToDateFormat(long mills) {

        Date date = new Date(mills);
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        String dateFormatted = formatter.format(date);
        return dateFormatted; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the API DateTime from JodaTime and make something like this:

```
    Date date = new Date();
    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(date);
    DateTime newDateTime = dateTime.minusHours(5).minusMinutes(45);
```

Comment: I'm guessing OP is doing an exercise from a book/course, so JodaTime wouldn't be allowed. Java 8 has (pretty much) the same API as JodaTime, to it's no longer needed unless you're stuck with Java <= 7

Comment: It's OP I agree, but with one line and everyone who reads the code know what he is doing really fast, using Calendar or Date the code gonna be alot more verbose. If you can't use some other dependency use like the @Vadim answer

Comment: The Joda-Time project, now in maintenance mode, advises moving to the java.time classes.

Answer (score 1):

How about stay out of dependencies?

```
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -i);
        Calendar calLess5_45 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calLess5_45.setTimeInMillis(cal.getTimeInMillis() - (1000*60*45) - (1000*60*60*5));
```

or with Date:

```
        Date initialDate = cal.getTime();
        Date dateLess5_45 = new Date(initialDate.getTime() - (1000*60*45) - (1000*60*60*5));
```

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

The troublesome old date-time classes are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date and in adding subtracting days. The date, and length of day, varies around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdtNow = ZonedDateTime.now( z );
```

Subtract a day. Accounts for anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtYesterday = zdtNow.minusDays( 1 );
```

Subtract a duration of five hours and forty-five minutes.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofHours( 5 ).plusMinutes( 45 );  // or Duration.parse( "PT5H45M" ) in standard ISO 8601 string format.
ZonedDateTime zdtEarlier = zdtYesterday.minus( d ) ;
```